# Application not found in PATH

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, shell, path

I am using Red Hat SunOS. The software I would like to execute is sqlplus

I have two scripts:

1. script A: contains `export PATH=/opt/oracle/product/9.2.0/bin/sqlplus` where sqlplus is installed. This script calls the script B
2. script B: contains `echo $PATH` and right after `which sqlplus`. 
   The fist command print the content of PATH which contains

> /opt/oracle/product/9.2.0/bin/sqlplus

The latter command does **NOT** found in which path sqlplus is installed.

I tried executing the commands directly in the bash shell:
`export PATH=/opt/oracle/product/9.2.0/bin/sqlplus`

`which sqlplus`

> /opt/oracle/product/9.2.0/bin/sqlplus

My question is:

- Why the script B cannot found where sqlplus is installed?

Comment: Is `sqlplus` a file or a directory?

Comment: The PATH compoeoent should be `/opt/oracle/product/9.2.0/bin/` (ie a directory where `sqlplus` can be found, not the command itself).

Comment: How does the second command even work when you clobbered your path with a single directory?  The ***which*** command is usually in /usr/bin.  /usr/bin is not in your path at the moment you export PATH=blah blah blah without a ***:$PATH*** in it.  Something like `export PATH=$PATH:/opt/oracle/product/9.2.0/bin/`

Comment: Thanks, that's right sqlplus is a binary